# Need some assistance with 2 SQL queries

Tags: sql

I need some help with my exam, there are 2 questions but I don't know how to join them and which SQL statements I need.

1. Write a SQL statement which displays the employee id, last name,and salary of any employee whose salary is above the price of the most expensive product.
2. Write a SQL statement which displays the customer id of customers who purchased the product with product_id 1 but so far never purchased the product with product_id 3.

It would be nice if somebody explain me the solution.

[image]

Comment: Stop asking others to help you cheat and just go cheat by yourself and read a few tutorials on joins.

Comment: You should really attempt to answer this yourself and when you are stuck provide any work you have done and ask about a specific problem. This site isn't a place to get your homework done.

Comment: What have you come up with so far? This isn't a cheat at school site, it's a help people who try to help themselves site.

Comment: You **can** get help with homework on this site, but you need ask a specific question, not just "here's my homework, please explain the solution".

Comment: @Blorgbeard agreed, I don't mind **helping**, but I am not going to do it for you. =)

Comment: So: How far did you get, where are you stuck, what specifically do you not understand? If you don't know how to start, you need to get further on your own (or with a tutor's help) before asking on SO.

Comment: Yes, there is a big difference between "help me with this part of my homework" and "do my homework."

Comment: @M6Gpower have you read your lesson information and at least done a few google searches on `SQL JOIN`s? Your question doesn't show that you have even attempted to learn the material.

Comment: No joins needed in either of the answers.  1st query simply needs a select and a subquery on employees and (subquery max product price).  2nd query needs a correlated subquery on purchases (find all customers wiht product 1 purchases whose customer ID that does not exist the set of customers having purchased product 3 .  All the other tables are ***Noise*** and not needed for the results you're after. 1st query 13 words.  2nd query about 23.

Comment: Yes i saw few many tutorials about the Join operation and its simple but how to Join tables without a relation? , There is no PK, FK between "employees" and "products"

Comment: No, but you don't need a relation, you need to just find employees with a higher salary than the highest priced product. Write a query to find the highest priced product, then use that find the employees with salary greater than that. (`sub-query`).

Comment: So the first one is SELECT max(price) FROM Products and then?

Comment: The first one is: a query limited by the results of a sub-query. You should really attempt to write it yourself. If you fail that, then post your query and ask why it is wrong.

Comment: When working with SQL think of data in terms of SETS of data.  1st query: you need a set of data consisting of the highest price product.  you then need a set of data for all the employees whose salary exceeds that.  The 2nd query you need a set of data for all customers having purchased product 1 and a set of all customers having purchased product 3.  now you need to exclude those records from the first set which are in the 2nd set.

Comment: i dont have the Tables in a Database managment system , i dont know if it fail or not ... whats wrong with you guys , i dont ask for joking .

Comment: ***"whats wrong with you guys "*** Your question.  If you simply have a "TEST EXAM" but it is missing two answers and you'd like to know what they are then ask that.  but you asked us to help you with an EXAM question.  that's is cheating and we don't like to do that here.  Also we help those who try and help themselves.  You've shown no attempt at the answers... Do that and you'll get much more joy.

Comment: Which student is writing an Exam on 21:37 o Clock men , what are you talking about , this is just a text exam without solution.

Comment: 2:37PM here... sounds like a good time for an exam.  WWW has many timezones.  Per the 2nd comment.  so this isn't a GRADED test?  The word EXAM implies a test with grade.  if this is a PRACTICE test that's one thing...  So to stop escalation..... Show us what you've tried.  We'll help.

Comment: Dude why you discuss with me about something else .

Comment: your comment of "So the first one is SELECT max(price) FROM Products and then?" is correct as it's the 1st piece but then you need to use it in the where clause of the employee to compare salary.  I do recommend updating your question to indicate that it is a practice exam, and show what you tried to do for each question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the understanding this is a practice exam, and that you don't have access to the tables/values....

You really should show what you've tried... but since you're new...

Question 1: 
Return employeeID, last name and salary of all employees who have a salary greater than the price of the most expensive product (like how they avoided using the word max there...)

So this uses a subquery to get the max price from products and simply compares salary against it.

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Last_Name, Salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary > (Select max(price) from Products);
```

Question 2:

Generate two sets one for product_ID of 1 one for product_ID of 3 and make sure those with 1 are not in the group with 3.

and this uses a correlated subquery  (notice how the PUR alias is in the subquery? that's why it's correlated)

So the first query gets all the customers buying product 1.  The 2nd query finds all the customers buying product 3.  and since we want only those customers who bought 1 not 3, we correlate the queries using not exists and we have our answer.

Exists - usually fastest as it can early exit the subquery once a single record for a customer is found.

```
SELECT Distinct PUR.Customer_ID 
FROM purchases PUR
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1
  and not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Purchases PUR2
                  WHERE Product_ID = 3
                    and PUR.Customer_ID = PUR2.Customer_I
```

There are 2-3 ways of doing this.  I find the above the most efficient in most cases.  However you could also do it by... a self join; or using an not IN statement

Self LEFT join (works great if you need data from multiple tables

We self join on purchases but filter each table instance to be for a specific product.  we use left join as we want all records with product Id 1 and where a match is found in p2, we want to EXCLUDE those records  so if the customer_ID is null that means they have no product 3 purchases

```
SELECT Distinct P1.customer_ID
FROM Purchases P1
LEFT JOIN Purchase P2
 on P1.customer_Id = P2.customer_ID
and P2.Product_ID = 3
WHERE P1.Product_ID = 1
 and P2.customer_ID is null
```

not in (usually slowest but works fine if subquery is for a VERY Small datasets)

```
SELECT Distinct PUR.Customer_ID 
FROM purchases PUR
WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1 
  and customer_ID not in (SELECT Customer_Id 
                          FROM Purchases
                          WHERE Product_ID = 3)
```

Notice that neither of the 1st two answers uses a join; though a correlated  subquery is close.

Comment: ok one more question , where is column "Pur" in Purchases or is this just like "as" operation to rename it.

Comment: the PUR is an alias like a column alias; but in this case for a table  You just don't have to use the keyword 'as'.  The reason I used one is so I can CORRELATE the inner and outer query.  Otherwise the db engine will not know which Purchases table I mean.  So I needed aliases.

Comment: thanks for the explanation !